# Merge xml files using Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xml

I have 2 files named file1.xml and file2.xml respectively. The contents of the files are:

**file1.xml**:

```
<EJB:Service>
    <EJB:ServiceId>123</EJB:ServiceId>
    <EJB:ServiceName>Checkin</EJB:ServiceName>
    <EJB:JndiName>datasource</EJB:JndiName>
    <EJB:HomeClassName>local</EJB:HomeClassName>
    <EJB:ServerName>Weblogic12345</EJB:ServerName>
</EJB:Service>

<EJB:Service>
    <EJB:ServiceId>456</EJB:ServiceId>
    <EJB:ServiceName>local</EJB:ServiceName>
    <EJB:JndiName>source</EJB:JndiName>
    <EJB:HomeClassName>local</EJB:HomeClassName>
    <EJB:ServerName>Weblogic</EJB:ServerName>
</EJB:Service>
```

**file2.xml**:

```
<EJB:Service>
    <EJB:ServiceId>123</EJB:ServiceId>
    <EJB:ServiceName>Booking</EJB:ServiceName>
    <EJB:JndiName>class</EJB:JndiName>
    <EJB:HomeClassName>Home</EJB:HomeClassName>
    <EJB:ServerName>Weblogic</EJB:ServerName>
</EJB:Service>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<EJB:Service>
    <EJB:ServiceId>123</EJB:ServiceId>
    <EJB:ServiceName>Booking</EJB:ServiceName>
    <EJB:JndiName>class</EJB:JndiName>
    <EJB:HomeClassName>Home</EJB:HomeClassName>
    <EJB:ServerName>Weblogic</EJB:ServerName>
</EJB:Service>

<EJB:Service>
    <EJB:ServiceId>456</EJB:ServiceId>
    <EJB:ServiceName>local</EJB:ServiceName>
    <EJB:JndiName>source</EJB:JndiName>
    <EJB:HomeClassName>local</EJB:HomeClassName>
    <EJB:ServerName>Weblogic</EJB:ServerName>
</EJB:Service>
```

How do i merge these files to get the desired output using Linux shell scripting?

Comment: Feel you free to give it a look in some other posts [ [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004135/merge-multiple-xml-files-from-command-line), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11315257/3569208), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372604/python-elementtree-parsing-unbound-prefix-error) ... ] and similar solutions just existing. A question: why do you need to parse xml files in with a shell script instead to find commands and programs just made for it?